# Google Maps Directions API Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-directions-api

I want to get data from google directions API. When I open the google directions API link on the browser it is giving me correct result.

But when I try to get some of those datas for example routes, it's giving me an NullPointerException. How is can be null ? I can get data from other API with the same code. But I can't take the data from this API. 
I've enabled billing account for this project. But there is some warning in my billing account : 
"Your payment information could not be processed. Visit the payment overview page to make sure your payment information is up to date and to pay any outstanding charges."
It can be a problem ? Please help me to find where the problem is. Thank you in advance

Comment: Would you mind sharing a code that demonstrates your issue. Otherwise it's really difficult to say something.

Comment: It looks like you are getting an error due to a billing issue. Please make sure that your billing account is in good standing. For further assistance, you may file a support case through this link: https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support